# OS.FileSys.mkDir that does not raise exception when the directory already exists

Tags: sml

I am trying to write a function that creates a directory but does not raise an error when the directory already exists. This is the function:

```ml
fun ensureDir s =
  (OS.FileSys.mkDir s)
  handle OS.SysErr (_, SOME Posix.Error.exist) => ()
```

I based the pattern `OS.SysErr (_, SOME Posix.Error.exist)` on the fact that `OS.FileSys.mkDir` fails with the following error message when the directory already exists:

- Poly/ML:

  ```
  Exception- SysErr ("File exists", SOME EEXIST) raised
  ```
- SML/NJ:

  ```
  uncaught exception SysErr [SysErr: File exists [exist]]
    raised at: <mkdir.c>
  ```

However, I get this error when I try to define the function in the Poly/ML shell:

```
poly: : error: qualified name Posix.Error.exist illegal here
Static Errors
```

This is the error in SML/NJ:

```
Error: variable found where constructor is required: Posix.Error.exist
```

What mistake did I make in the function definition?

(Poly/ML 5.7.1; SML/NJ 110.79; Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Posix.Error.exist` is a `val` and not a constructor (like `SOME`) so
you cannot use it as a pattern in a pattern matching construct.  Here
is an equivalent code for what you intended to do.

```ml
fun ensureDir s =
  (OS.FileSys.mkDir s)
  handle e as (OS.SysErr (_, SOME err)) =>
      if err = Posix.Error.exist
      then ()
      else raise e
;
```